# Why can't I create html element dynamically?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create paragraph dynamic,so I wrote the following code. After user click the button, a new paragraph whose innerText is the user's inputs should be added.But I failed, Is there someone can help me?

```js
var input = document.querySelector(".input");
var btn = document.querySelector("button");
var body = document.querySelector("body");

btn.addEventListener('click', addParagraph);

function addParagraph() {
  var childELes = body.children;
  for (var p in childELes) {
    if (p.tagName === "p")
      p.remove();
  }
  if (input.value.trim() != "") {
    var newPara = document.createElement("p");
    newPara.innerText = input.value;
    body.appendChild(newPara);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>test</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form>
    <p>
      <label>input：</label>
      <input type="text" class="input">
      <button>add</button>
    </p>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Just add `.preventDefault()` when dealing with clicks

https://jsfiddle.net/ta9pxbLc/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is working but the form is being submitted that is why the dynamically added value get lost and page is refreshed. To make it work as you expect, you need to use `e.preventDefault();` to prevent the form from being submitted:

```js
var input = document.querySelector(".input");
var btn = document.querySelector("button");
var body = document.querySelector("body");

btn.addEventListener('click', addParagraph);

function addParagraph(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var childELes = body.children;
  for (var p in childELes) {
    if (p.tagName === "p")
      p.remove();
  }
  if (input.value.trim() != "") {
    var newPara = document.createElement("p");
    newPara.innerText = input.value;
    body.appendChild(newPara);
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  <p>
    <label>input：</label>
    <input type="text" class="input">
    <button>add</button>
  </p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add `type="button"` to your button html tag:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <p>
            <label>input：</label>
            <input type="text" class="input">
            <button type="button">add</button>
        </p>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var input = document.querySelector(".input");
    var btn = document.querySelector("button");
    var body = document.querySelector("body");

    btn.addEventListener('click', addParagraph);

    function addParagraph() {
        var childELes = body.children;
        for (var p in childELes) {
            if (p.tagName === "p")
                p.remove();
        }
        if (input.value.trim() != "") {
            var newPara = document.createElement("p");
            newPara.innerText = input.value;
            body.appendChild(newPara);
        }
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just add `.preventDefault()` to prevent the `button` from refreshing the page.

```js
var input = document.querySelector(".input");
var btn = document.querySelector("button");
var body = document.querySelector("body");

btn.addEventListener('click', addParagraph);

function addParagraph(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
  var childELes = body.children;
  for (var p in childELes) {
    if (p.tagName === "p")
      p.remove();
  }
  if (input.value.trim() != "") {
    var newPara = document.createElement("p");
    newPara.innerText = input.value;
    body.appendChild(newPara);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form>
      <p>
        <label>input：</label>
        <input type="text" class="input">
        <button>add</button>
      </p>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because the button in form invokes a `submit` and reloads the page. You see the new `p-tag` for short time. But the page reloads and all `p` a gone.

Add `type="button"` to your button to exclude it as submit button or use `event.preventDefault()` in your button event.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is 100% correct the only problem happening is your   `<button>add</button>` is doing a postback which is refreshing your page.

You just need to add a type of button to your button tag and it will work like this:

`<button type="button">add</button>`

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

```
function addParagraph(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var a = document.getElementById("inserted-p");
  if(a != null) {a.remove();}
  if (input.value.trim() != "") {
    var newPara = document.createElement("p");
    newPara.id = "inserted-p";
    newPara.innerText = input.value;
    body.appendChild(newPara);
  }
}
```

1. Your form is being sent, so prevent it by calling `e.preventDefault()`
2. Your remove is not working, because `p` is not a direct child of `body`, so fix it by adding `id` to your inserted element and removing tag with proper selector